# what is my heroku hostname? development is localhost:3000, what's production name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, host

Setting up a mailer. It works in localhost, however, it doesn't send the email, just gives me the message in the log. My development.rb is:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

I tried this for my production.rb but it didn't work.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://cryptic-reef-1625.herokuapp.com/" }
```

I get an error when I hit the button that sends the email.

Comment: You need to add SMTP configuration. Also, please include error messages with your question, that is usually where the answer lies.

Comment: See the guide for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your environment.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
Make sure you change host to your production url and keep it localhost for development. This is for the mailer, it needs a default email to send out notices such as confirmations etc...